# Realm Migration 0.81.1 to latest 1.1.0 version

Tags: android, migration, realm

My playstore version of realm was `0.81.1` and i had done migration with latest realm version `1.1.0` for the next playstore version after then

> error for Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmObjectSchema
>   io.realm.RealmObjectSchema.addField(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class,
>   io.realm.FieldAttribute[])' on a null object reference

Please help me who known realm migration very well.

Comment: Could you show us your migration code?